# How to connect a multiple PCs to certain Database via WIFI?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, share

I created DB by SQL Server Compact Edition for my company and, I want every employee in a office that I give him a privilege to connect to that Database and see the tables by using the company's WIFI network

The question is how to make it possible "Share my Database over Wifi connection to other computers connected to same Wifi?

Comment: I see. Well, if that's the requirement, then good luck. By the way, is there actually a question?

Comment: Your question will probably be closed: it's vague, not necessarily programming related, and it doesn't sound like you've done any research. Take a look at the "help" section of this site, particularly http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you want to connect multiple users to a database - use a real, server-based version, like SQL Server Express or Standard; SQL Server Compact is just not designed / intended for this

Comment: not necessarily programming related , WHAT! ... are you kidding me ?

Comment: @marc_s is there a way to convert my DB from SQL Server Ce to SQL Server-based ?

Comment: @user2965463: Sounds like you think it is programming related: what language are you writing your code in? Are you planning on writing the code to share the database?

Comment: Look at [Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.com) - Erik has a ton of good insight and tools to deal with SQL Server CE and the server-based SQL Server versions

Comment: @DaveRook Dear it's not my home work , i wanted to share my code but i have no problem with my code IT'S OKAY ... 
I'm gonna share my if the privacy of this site compulsory !!!

Comment: What language is it in? I think you need to create an web page, set up on IIS and share it over a local Intranet then you can just query the database

Comment: @DaveRook I've used C# ?

Comment: @user2965463, in that case, use EF, LinqToSql or Ado.net and query the database within a WebForm or MVC. Publish these files to your local server, or your local machine, open up the relevant ports and configure it in IIS and use your local server/machine as a webserver. Then, everyone in the office can view the database via webpage. It really isn't that daunting as it sounds  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the company's network infrastructure and not database . If you set your network on wifi then you can connect to database true network.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comments, you have a database and a C# program (software or web is unknown) and you want to connect to it.

Your question is actually about what technology to use. This is up for debate but personally, I would:

Create a Webform or MVC package.
Share the website via IIS on your local machine. Make sure to open port 80.
In your code, query the database and show the results in a DataGrid or within a repeater(or similar control).

Now you can share your page via the Intranet. This can updated to allow full CRUD control if you wanted, or can be read only.